# Getting HTML textbox input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need some help with ASP.NET.

I have an html page that has a form tag with a couple of input tags and I want to do a Post.

Now on the server, I'm implementing IHTTPHandler. I get the response, but i don't see my input data.

How can i get what the user types in into the input tags in the http handler. I was able to do this before. But now i can't find where in the context object the results are.

Comment: Aren't they supposed to be `Request` variables?

Comment: @Adrian - This is an HTML file, not an ASPX file

Comment: I know. Still, it's supposed to be in the `Request` object. It's a HTTP Request. Look at the answers. It looks so trivial that I did not answer because I though I was missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="txtId"></input>

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
   var element = context.Request["txtId"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try Request["Tag's Name"] so for example to get the value from

```
<input type="text" name="firstname"></input>
```

use

```
Request["firstname"]
```

in your code behind.